# Cannot find name 'Math'

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular7 and following tour-of-heroes application. I created InMemoryDataService class and trying to generated id but getting Error 
"[ts] Cannot find name 'Math'." I also try to add Math package with NPM command but error is still there.

Tried to Install Math package with NPM command .

```
genId(users: User[] ): number {
    return (<any>users).length > 0 ? Math.max( ...(<any>users).map( user => user.userId ) ) + 1 : 11;
}
```

I am not able to use Math class.

Comment: `Math` is a global property of `window`. You don't need to install or import its. It work in browser "out of the box"

Comment: Do you have any `Math.xxx` in your template ? That might be your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Math` is not a class; it's a global object required to exist by the ECMA specification in the global scope, so there's no need to install it (with `npm` or otherwise). It's just there and it should be available to you.

Make sure you're including at least the `es5` lib in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"lib": ["es5"]
```